# ElasticSearch and Kibana: compare value with aggregated value

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch

I'm wondering how to accomplish this requirement. 
I have to compare value data with the average over the selected period or over another period.

I've collected millions of records in an index. These records contains the sellout amount day by day for different vendors, products, sectors and product families.

What I'd like to do is to analyse any single value with the average of the selected period of the average of the same periodo of a previous year. I'd like to use Kibana to show data to users.

How can I accomplish it?

Thanks